# On the process of communication and object method wait（）

Tags: java, multithreading

```
//Two threads, one print a-z, and one print A-Z
public class ThreadPrint {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Object obj=new Object();


    Thread1 t1=new Thread1(obj);
    Thread2 t2=new Thread2(obj);
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
}

 //The first thread
class Thread1 extends Thread
{

private Object obj;
public Thread1(Object obj)
{
    this.obj=obj;
}

    public void run()
    {
     //Synchronize code blocks

        synchronized(obj)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<26;i++)
            {
               //print
                System.out.println((char)('a'+i)+" ");
                //Wake-up process
                obj.notifyAll();
                  try
                    {
                        if(i!=25)
                        {

                        obj.wait();
                        }
                    }
                    catch(InterruptedException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
  } 



class Thread2 extends Thread
{
    private Object obj;
    public Thread2(Object obj) 
    {
        this.obj=obj;
    }
    public void run()
    {
  //synchronized code blocks
        synchronized(obj)
        {
        for(int i=0;i<26;i++)
        {
            System.out.println((char)('A'+i)+" ");
     //Wake up to a previous process
            obj.notifyAll();    
                try
                {
                    if(i!=25)
                    {
                    obj.wait();
                    }
                }
                catch(InterruptedException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    }
 }

}





Console:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
No enclosing instance of type ThreadPrint is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type ThreadPrint (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of ThreadPrint).
```

I know it mean Process is not synchronized.My first thought was put to wait(obj) before synchronized（obj）.

```
  Unhandled exception type InterruptedException
```

As you see,I cannot solve it.
       How to  solve it in code?
       Why not obj.wait() not befor synchronized(obj)?
Test Conditions:
JDK1.8  IDE:Eclipse.

Comment: Neither of those compilation errors has anything to do with synchronization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compilation issues are the ones which occur during code compile and not during application run time. If you have got compilation issues, it simply means some where some syntax in your code does not match the correct grammar of the programming language.

In your code Class `Thread1` and `Thread2` are inner classes (declared as non static classes within curly braces of class `ThreadPrint`). To instantiate the object of a non static inner class you need an object of outer enclosing class. You have tried to create the object of `Thread1` and `Thread2` without creating and using object of `ThreadPrint`. This causes the initial issue you mentioned.

Also note that `wait` ,`notify` and `notifyall` methods should only  be called by a thread that is the owner of the object's monitor(upon which these methods are being invoked), i.e. call them only from within `synchronized block`. So your thought of putting wait before `synchronized block` will not work.  Also note that `wait` method must be called from within a loop. Method `wait` should be invoked when we wish a task to get completed whose notification current thread will get when some other thread notifies the current thread. Upon being notified the task completion status must be verified in a loop to prevent the current thread waking up and proceed ahead due to any other notification or from some interrupt. ( refer : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html )

You have three options:

1. Simply create the object of outer enclosing class `ThreadPrint` and then using that object create the objects of `Thread1` and `Thread2`.
2. Decrare the classes `Thread1` and `Thread2` as `static`.
3. Declare the classes `Thread1` and `Thread2` in their own  separate java files.

Comment: Yes，your options is very good.I take it ,but in your options 3.What your mean?

Comment: In option 3, I meant you can create Thread1 and Thread2 in their seprate java file, like you have created a .java file for ThreadPrint, like wise you can have a class for Thread1 and another for Thread2. Now you do not need to declare them static and also you do not need to create the object of ThreadPrint to create the objects of Thread1 and Thread2.

Comment: Thank you very much.I use you option 2 and option3. to solve my problem.Self-learning Java is very problem.Where is your blog.I want to learn

Comment: Thank you very much.If you have enough time.Can you give me the  code for options1.

Comment: Options4：We can put Thread1 and Thread2 before ThreadPrint.we do not need created java file.

Comment: For option1 you can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856808/instantiate-inner-class-object-from-current-outer-class-object