# Java 8 Innner Class Instantiation

Tags: java, java-8, inner-classes

Why does this code not compile. I am learning to Predicate in Java. Here is the code

```
package com.java8.lambda.predicate;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import com.java8.lambda.pojo.Employee;

public class PredicateSample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee permanentEmployee = new Employee(70, "Jagmohan", "Sanyal", new Date(), 'M', 19900.87,"P");
        Employee tempEmployee = new Employee(70, "Shruti", "Bhatia", new Date(), 'F', 1990.87,"C");

        List<Employee> empList = new ArrayList<>();
        empList.add(permanentEmployee);
        empList.add(tempEmployee);

        PredicateSample predicateSample = new PredicateSample();
        //Code doesn't compile on this line due to non-visibility of EmployeePredicate class
        //It fails with "PredicateSample.EmployeePredicate cannot be resolved to a type"
        EmployeePredicate empPredicate = new PredicateSample().new EmployeePredicate();
    }

}

class EmployeePredicate {

    public Predicate<Employee> getOlderEmployee(){
        return p -> p.getAge() > 60  && p.getEmploymentType().equalsIgnoreCase("P");
    }

    public List<Employee> filter(List<Employee> employees, Predicate<Employee> p){
        return employees.stream().filter(p).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

I have already gone through the following link [Inner Class Instantiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856808/instantiate-inner-class-object-from-current-outer-class-object)

I also went through to other sites but not able to figure out the problem.

Comment: `EmployeePredicate` is not an inner class of `PredicateSample`

Answer (score 2):

You need the inner class to actually **be** an **inner** class.

```
public class PredicateSample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee permanentEmployee = new Employee(70, "Jagmohan", "Sanyal", new Date(), 'M', 19900.87,"P");
        Employee tempEmployee = new Employee(70, "Shruti", "Bhatia", new Date(), 'F', 1990.87,"C");

        List<Employee> empList = new ArrayList<>();
        empList.add(permanentEmployee);
        empList.add(tempEmployee);

        PredicateSample predicateSample = new PredicateSample();
        //Code doesn't compile on this line due to non-visibility of EmployeePredicate class
        //It fails with "PredicateSample.EmployeePredicate cannot be resolved to a type"
        EmployeePredicate empPredicate = new PredicateSample().new EmployeePredicate();
    }

    // **inner** class.
    class EmployeePredicate {

        public Predicate<Employee> getOlderEmployee(){
            return p -> p.getAge() > 60  && p.getEmploymentType().equalsIgnoreCase("P");
        }

        public List<Employee> filter(List<Employee> employees, Predicate<Employee> p){
            return employees.stream().filter(p).collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
    } // < --- end of **inner** class
} // < --- end of **outer** class.
```